# Регулярные выражения. Замена английский символов на русские. C#

Tags: c#

К своему стыду и сожалению, в регулярных выражениях не очень силен.

Необходимо заменить все английские буквы, которые схожи по написанию с русскими/украинскими на их русские/украинские аналоги. Например "a" англ. на "а" русское и т.д.

Пишу на C#. Задайте хоть правильное направление, как это сделать.

Представляю себе регулярное выражение в каком-то таком виде:

```
string regexPattern = "[eEKTpPaAcCxXMiIHBoO]";
var regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
```

а дальше что делать - не знаю. Не уверен также, что правильно записано само регулярное выражение.

Comment: А зачем вообще регулярка? Просто вам нужен словарь замен и `string.Replace` в цикле по всем «плохим» буквам.

Comment: @VladD, мне почему-то казалось, что регулярками это можно сделать быстрее и лаконичнее. Просто в цикле нужно будет записать большое к-ство if-условий

Comment: @VladD это же создаст кучу новых строк. По-моему, лучше воспользоваться `StringBuilder`-ом.

Comment: @Ep1demic у вас ведь весьма специфичные условия замены, для которых написать рег. выражение замены весьма проблемно. Поэтому использование словаря замен (или объединение символов в группы с заданными правилами преобразования, если в этом есть смысл) звучит разумнее.

Comment: @Regent: Ну да, но это уже оптимизация. Написал в ответе именно так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, в вашем случае использовать регулярки нерационально. Достаточно объявить словарь с заменами. Получится достаточно компактно:

```
static string Cyrillify(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    foreach (var kvp in Replacements)
        sb.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    return sb.ToString();
}

static Dictionary<char, char> Replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    ['a'] = 'а',
    ['A'] = 'А',
    ['B'] = 'В',
    ['c'] = 'с',
    ['C'] = 'С',
    ['e'] = 'е',
    ['E'] = 'Е',
    ['H'] = 'Н',
    ['i'] = 'і',
    ['I'] = 'І',
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо!

Comment: @Ep1demic: Пожалуйста!